# Unload JavaScript Libraries without knowing their namespace

Tags: javascript, import, namespaces

I'd like to know whether theres a possibility to unload JavaScript libraries
(e.g. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`) without knowing its namespace. I removed the  element but jQuery is still available. Obviously I could just wipe $ and jQuery away but thats not what I'd like to achieve.

This question is **not** about jQuery, it could be any arbitrary JavaScript Import.

**Edit:**

To reverse my question is it possible to resolve a functions origin, like the browsers do in their Inspectors? Like function is defined at Line 360 in Import X?

Thank you!
Alessandro

Comment: You would have to remove *all* references to the (unknown) namespace. So I don't think that's possible.

Comment: You can't just reverse the effects of executing a script.

Comment: The only way I see is to create a snapshot of all user defined global variables before and after the you included the script. Then you could revert those that have changed and delete those that are new. Of course this wouldn't catch modifications to existing objects, like extending native prototype objects. As already said, you cannot "undo" a script.

Comment: Is there a way to namespace an import? like binding all <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> to a certain namespace, so that this namespace could be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of  tags as module was a wrong approach at the problem. The answer is use modules from ES6 or AMD/CJS through e.g. requireJS which *can* include functionality to unload/deallocate things properly and thus provide a lifecycle.